# How Can I use preg_match

Tags: php, string, function

I just want to ask how to find some text in a string. I know that I will gonna use `preg_match` function in PHP but I don't know how to use it. Let's say I want to make a web hosting. Shall I do like this:

```
<?php
$web_hosting_service="hostingservice.com";
$subdomain_name = "subdomain.hostingservice.com";

if(preg_match($web_hosting_service, $subdomain_service) {
  echo 'true';
} else {
echo 'false';
}
```

If not, what I need to do

Comment: You are missing delimiters for your regex and you also want to escape your search string, so you take away the special meaning for specific characters. Also you could use `strpos()`, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple string-within-a-string checking, use `strstr` instead of `preg_match`.  It's much simpler:

```
<?php
$web_hosting_service="hostingservice.com";
$subdomain_name = "subdomain.hostingservice.com";

if(strstr($subdomain_name, $web_hosting_service)) {
   echo 'true';
}
```